# Excel 2010 - CELL function not returning Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, filenames, cells

All over the INTERNET I found that `CELL` function returns the full file path, the Drive letter, Workbook and Sheet name in a format of `C:\Folder\[workbook.xlsm] sheetname` more or less by entering the following formula into a cell,

`=CELL("filename",A1)`

Doesn't work...at least not for me.

I do not get `path [workbook.xlsm] Sheet name`, which is the format every site states should be the result, and instead I get,

`C:\Users\jsmith\Documents\Inventory.xlsm`.

No brackets, No sheet name.

Can any one suggest me how to fix this issue!

Comment: Try just `=CELL("filename")` and make sure you have saved the workbook. FYI the sheet it lists is the active sheet in the workbook so make sure a sheet is actually active

Comment: Nothing wrong with Formula, it should `=Cell("Filename")` or even `=Cell("Filename,A1)` is working without any problem for me!!

Answer (score 0):

I found that if the sheet name is the same as the file name "and" there is only one sheet (tab) in the workbook then the brackets and sheet name are not included in the returned string (dropped).  Make sure your sheet name is different from your (saved) file name or that there are at least two sheets (tabs) in your workbook.